# How to draw following figure or similar using tikz and pgf

Tags: latex, tikz

My thesis superviser asks to redraw this picture in order to cite it in my paper. Could someone help how? Maybe there is a software that can make drawn picture a latex code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ramZQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577) And please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will get you started. First make a suitable layout of the boxes by editing the foreach loop. After that, make the boxes one-by-one, e.g.

```
\draw (2,7) node[rectangle,fill=green!20]{$C$};
\draw (3,7) node[rectangle,fill=green!20]{$T_1$};
```

[image: Blocks]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={signal, draw, signal to=north}]
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,rounded corners=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\filldraw[fill=blue!30!white,very thick] (1,4) rectangle (9,8);
\foreach \x in {2,3,4,5,6,7,8} {
\draw (\x,3) node[block,fill=yellow!50]{text};
\draw (\x,5) node[rectangle,fill=red!20]{text};
\draw (\x,7) node[rectangle,fill=green!20]{text};
\draw[->,line width=1mm] (\x,3.5) -- (\x,4.5);
}


\begin{scope}[shift={(13,0)}]
% #1, code needed also below
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,rounded corners=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(15,-0.2)}]
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,rounded corners=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(17,-0.4)}]
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,rounded corners=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw (0,0) circle (2pt);

\filldraw[fill=gray!20,rounded corners=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
% copy paste contents from #1 and edit a little
\filldraw[fill=blue!30!white,very thick] (1,4) rectangle (9,8);
\foreach \x in {2,3,4,5,6,7,8} {
\draw (\x,3) node[block,fill=yellow!50]{text};
\draw (\x,5) node[rectangle,fill=red!20]{text};
\draw (\x,7) node[rectangle,fill=green!20]{text};
\draw[->,line width=1mm] (\x,3.5) -- (\x,4.5);
}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ask you something?

Comment: @Paul Sure, you can ask me.